how to set header in yaml config for rest-client in quarkus
how is possible to define a custom header in the rest-client yaml configuration in quarkus? the following config does not work, headaer-name is not provided in the client request, I need to provide for example api-key as header
   quarkus:
     rest-client:
       my-client-name:
        url: https://api.com
        headers:
          headaer-name: header-value

I have the client autogenerated by quarkus from openapi file using the following dependencies
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkiverse.openapi.generator</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-openapi-generator</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-rest-client-reactive-jackson</artifactId>
    </dependency>


Take a look at https://quarkus.io/guides/rest-client#custom-headers-support
